# How can I calculate the epoche inside awk from a date string?

Tags: awk

I have a file with data:

```
2022-05-03 00:00:05,11.9 kW
2022-05-03 00:00:15,11.8 kW
2022-05-03 00:00:25,11.9 kW
2022-05-03 00:00:35,11.9 kW
2022-05-03 00:00:45,11.9 kW
2022-05-03 00:00:55,11.9 kW
2022-05-03 00:01:05,11.9 kW
2022-05-03 00:01:15,12.0 kW
2022-05-03 00:01:25,12.0 kW
```

And this is my awk script to calculate the epoche time:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

/^[0-9]./ {
    print $1
       cmd="date -d \"$1\" +%s"
       cmd | getline $1
       close(cmd)
       print $1, $2
       next
}
```

The output that I expect is an ever-increasing epoch and the power reading:

```
1651528805 11.9 kW
1651528815 11.8 kW 
1651528825 11.9 kW 
1651528835 11.9 kW
1651528845 11.9 kW
...
```

However, instead I get a constant epoche value:

```
1655589600 11.9 kW
1655589600 11.8 kW
1655589600 11.9 kW
1655589600 11.9 kW
1655589600 11.9 kW
1655589600 11.9 kW
1655589600 11.9 kW
1655589600 12.0 kW
```

Why is that? Obviously, the epoche calculation does not work as intended. How do I correct that?

Comment: Which version of `awk` do you use?

Comment: nothing wrong with ur approach - `awk` is simply processing the rows too quickly for `date` to return a different value when precision is only at the # secs level. instead of `ms` or `ns`. I just do `gdate +'%s%6N'` (`%N` is always 3 more zeros with no extra info for my system anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Using gawk's [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), the argument to `mktime` is *space separated* "YYYY mm dd HH MM SS"

```
BEGIN {FS = ","}
{
  gsub(/[:-]/, " ", $1)
  epoch = mktime($1)
  print epoch, $2
}
```

Where your command is going wrong is putting `$1` *inside* double quotes:

```
cmd="date -d \"$1\" +%s"
# should be
cmd="date -d \"" $1 "\" +%s"
# or
cmd = sprintf("date -d \"%s\" +%%s", $1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '
    function epoche(dt){
        "date -d \""dt"\" +%s" | getline e; return e
    }
    {
        print epoche($1),$2
    }
    ' file

1651528805 11.9 kW
1651528815 11.8 kW
1651528825 11.9 kW
1651528835 11.9 kW
1651528845 11.9 kW
1651528855 11.9 kW
1651528865 11.9 kW
1651528875 12.0 kW
1651528885 12.0 kW
```